# Why do I have an empty “Searchable attributes” after import with 'algolia/scout-extended'?

Tags: algolia, laravel-scout

In a [Laravel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel) 9 application, I have *algolia/scout-extended 2.0*.

Running on my local OS command

```
php artisan scout:optimize
```

I got several files like *config/scout-search-pages.php*, and I modified one of them:

```
'searchableAttributes' => [
    'page_title',
    'page_slug',
    'page_content',
    'page_content_shortly',
    'page_author_name',
    'page_author_email',
    'page_price',
    'page_categories',
    'page_created_at',

],


'customRanking' => ['asc(page_price)', 'desc(page_created_at)'],
```

And clearing the cache I run an import and after that I see a set of rows/columns I expected: https://prnt.sc/Ew0BdaH3dvON

1. But on the “Configuration” tab I see an empty “Searchable attributes” list, and I have to add fields manually.
   I expected that these fields must be filled automatically from “searchableAttributes” option,
   but not.
2. After I added more columns at “Add a Searchable Attribute” I see “unordered/unordered” option for fields.
   How does it work and which option do I have to select?

The source table on MySQL 8 side has this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `search_pages` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `page_title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `page_slug` varchar(260) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `page_content` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `page_content_shortly` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `page_author_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `page_author_email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `page_price` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `page_categories` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `page_created_at` timestamp NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `search_pages_page_slug_unique` (`page_slug`),
  KEY `search_pages_page_author_name_page_title_index` (`page_author_name`,`page_title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```